# How can I pass php code as a content while publishing a post

Tags: php, wp-insert-post

I'm parsing JSON data and want to display it in a Wordpress post. Here's the code that I would like to publish. Any idea how I can include this in wp_insert_post.

```
$url = "http://metaweather.com/api/location/2379574";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
$weather_sate=$json_data['consolidated_weather'][0][weather_state_name]
$temperature=$json_data['consolidated_weather'][0][the_temp]
```

Comment: Describe your idea more clearly, please. Do you want to save weather data as post meta automatically on post save? Do you need to refresh weather data when you will decide to change post?  etc...

Comment: @anton I would like to save weather data as post menta automatically on psot save

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a simple example, which you can modify for your purpose. 
**save_weather_field**
This function will add/update/delete any post meta (in case you will decide to add more weather fields). We will use it inside post save action below.

```
function save_weather_field($post_id, $key, $value)
{
    //new value we pass in this function
    $new_meta_value = ( isset( $value ) ? sanitize_text_field( $value ) : false );

    //old value from database
    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, true );

    //if new value exists and old value not - we add post meta
    if ( $new_meta_value && false == $meta_value )
        add_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $new_meta_value, true );

    //if old value exists but we have new value - update post meta
    elseif ( $new_meta_value && $new_meta_value != $meta_value )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $new_meta_value );

    //if old value exists but new value is empty - delete post meta
    elseif ( false == $new_meta_value && $meta_value )
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $meta_value );

}
```

**weather_metadata_save**
This function fires on post save ("post" post type).

```
function weather_metadata_save($post_id, $post, $update){

    //return if user don't have permissions to edit post
    if(!current_user_can("edit_post", $post_id))
        return $post_id;

    //return if post submitted with XHR
    if(defined("DOING_AUTOSAVE") && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;

    //your code
    $url = "http://metaweather.com/api/location/2379574";
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $json_data = json_decode($json, true);
    $weather_sate=$json_data['consolidated_weather'][0]['weather_state_name'];
    $temperature=$json_data['consolidated_weather'][0]['the_temp'];

    /save weather sate if it exists
    if( !empty($weather_sate) ):
        save_weather_field($post_id, 'weather-sate', $weather_sate);
    endif;

    //save temperature if exists
    if( !empty($temperature) ):
        save_weather_field($post_id, 'temperature', $temperature);
    endif;
    
}

add_action("save_post_post", "weather_metadata_save", 10, 3);
```

I used `temperature` as post meta name for temperature and `weather-state` for weather state. So, you can get them as any other post meta:

```
$temperature = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'temperature', true);
$weather_state = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'weather-state', true);
```

P.S. I tried this code on my localhost, and I've got `27.195` and `Showers`, so I guess it works well ;)